# How to bind maven antrun plugin to the clean phase

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I have just translated an ant project into maven however since maven does not really deal with deployment I introduce some antrun into the build. However when I try to execute it the plugin skips my tasks. for exemple when I run mvn clean antrun:run I get the following message:   No ant target defined - SKIPPED. the same happends to the second phase in which I am trying to override the deployment phase to do an actual deploy rather to upload to a repository.

Please find below an extract of my pom.xml (type:pom):

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <task>
                            <echo>Cleaning deployed website</echo>
                        </task>
                        <tasks>
                            <delete dir="${deployRoot}/mydir/${env}"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deployment</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <task>
                            <echo>Deploying website</echo>
                        </task>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>Copying website artifact to deployment </echo>
                            <mkdir dir="${deployRoot}/mydir/${env}" />
                            <unzip
                                src="${project.basedir}/target/${env}.${project.version}.zip"
                                dest="${deployRoot}/mydir/${env}" />
                            <chmod perm="ugo+rx">
                                <fileset dir="${deployRoot}/mydir/${env}/web-exploded/bin">
                                    <include name="**/*.sh" />
                                    <include name="**/*.bat" />
                                </fileset>
                            </chmod>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `pom.xml`, you define two types of executions:

- One is linked to the `clean` phase
- One is linked to the `deploy` phase. Note, by the way, that for Maven, `deploy` does **not** mean *deploy my (web-)application on a server* but *deploy the artifact on a remote repository*. Please read the [`deploy` plugin information](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) for more details.

So if you run the command **mvn deploy**, when the Maven lifecycle reaches the `deploy` phase, it will run the plugin execution (the second one in your `pom.xml`).

However, in your case, you are **not** running the default Maven lifecycle, as your command is **mvn antrun:run** (I am not considering the `clean` goal here as it does not matter for the problem). This can be translated in Maven to *run the antrun plugin, with the goal run*. The problem with that is that you do not define any configuration (which contains the Ant tasks) for a *direct* call to your Ant plugin.

So two solutions:

- Bind the second execution to the `install` phase, and then run the `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn antrun:run`. Note that in this case, you will run the whole Maven lifecycle (i.e. compilation, tests, packaging).
- Create a configuration of this plugin that is **not** related to any execution. In XML point of view, simply add (or move) the second `<configuration>` block to be a child of the `<plugin>` definition.

If you choose the second solution, you will have a `pom.xml` like this one:

```
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <!-- For cleaning -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>clean</id>
                <configuration>
                    <task>
                        <echo>Cleaning deployed website</echo>
                    </task>
                    <tasks>
                        <delete dir="${deployRoot}/mydir/${env}"/>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <echo>Copying website artifact to deployment </echo>
                ...
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```